# Gettitng ReferenceError: "CryptoJS" is not defined

Tags: javascript, sha

I have written javascript to for RSASHA256 but gettitng error crypto.js is not defined.

```
 function aaa(message,secret) {
     <script src="http://crypto-
      js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js"></script>;
     <script src="http://crypto-
      js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js"></script>;
     var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
     var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
     document.write(hashInBase64);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why <script> is in js function ? put it into html head tag

Comment: What you have (when corrected) is nothing to do with RSA btw.

Comment: keep also in mind that in most cases, your js code will be visible, and even editable, crypting on the client side (for security reasons) is a bit pointless. Depending on what you want, maybe HTTPS will fit better.

Comment: I have written code as below to make in HmacSHA256 and that is working but but i need in RSASHA256 and for that is not working

 function aaa(message,secret) {
 var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("message", "secret");
 var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
 return aaa
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `<script>` tags inside your HTML.

```js
 function aaa(message,secret) {
     var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
     var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
     document.write(hashInBase64);
 }
```

```html
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/crypto-js.js">
```

Comment: I have written code as below to make in HmacSHA256 and that is working but but i need in RSASHA256 and for that is not working

 function aaa(message,secret) {
 var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("message", "secret");
 var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
 return aaa
 }

Comment: crypto js CDN Links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use script tag in html
2. or you can use jquery to load the script

   ```
   $.getScript("YourScriptOrLibraryFile.js", function(){
     //your code
   });
   ```

Comment: I have written code as below to make in HmacSHA256 and that is working but but i need in RSASHA256 and for that is not working

 function aaa(message,secret) {
 var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("message", "secret");
 var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
 return aaa
 }

Answer (score 0):

Hi my below code is working fine for HmacSHA256 not for RSASHA256,

```
 function aaa(message,secret) {
 var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256("Message", "secret");
 var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
 return aaa
 }
```